# Reading struct arrays from .txt file with for loop makes it loop for two times

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to c++ programming and i tried to use struct arrays ( dunno if I say it in the way you understand ). Program does read the variables from the text file but it reads it for 2 times, prob It's not a huge problem as the variables are not changed but just in case

```
struct menesine_temperatura
{
    int diena[10];
    int rytas[10];
    int pietus[10];
    int vakaras[10];
};


int main()
{
    menesine_temperatura mt;
    int n;
    ifstream failas("duomenys.txt");

    while(!failas.eof())
    {
        failas >> n;
        cout << n << endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            failas >> mt.diena[i] >> mt.rytas[i] >> mt.pietus[i] >> mt.vakaras[i];
            cout << mt.diena[i] << mt.rytas[i] << mt.pietus[i] << mt.vakaras[i] << endl;
        }

    }

    failas.close();

    return 0;
}
```

as I have mentioned before I' new to this stuff, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read this: [Why is iostream::eof considered wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Read this: [coding style - What is a magic number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad)

Comment: A little inquiry: from where have you learned to use `eof()`?

Comment: @LogicStuff i know eof() from pascal programming language, we'r learning pascal at school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code you have you, it will appear as if the last set of numbers are being read twice.

Here's a simple example that explains the logic error.

```
int main()
{
   int n; 
   std::ifstream inf("data.txt");
   while ( !inf.eof() )
   {
      inf >> n;
      std::cout << n << std::endl;
   }
}
```

and your input file consists of

```
10
20
```

In the first iteration of the loop, `10` is read into `n` and `10` is printed. 
In the second iteration of the loop, `20` is read into `n` and `20` is printed.

At this point `inf.eof()` is still `false`. So you enter the loop the third time. At this time, nothing is read into `n` but the value of `n` still `20` and `20` is printed.

The logic error is that just because `inf.eof()` is `false`, you assume that there is still some data in the file that can be read.

A better way would be to use:

```
int main()
{
   int n; 
   std::ifstream inf("data.txt");
   while ( inf )
   {
      if ( inf >> n )
      {
         std::cout << n << std::endl;
      }
   }
}
```

I hope this gives you enough information on how to update your program.

Comment: while( inf.peek() != EOF )  should be fine as well :)